# Objective-c asynchronous xml parser question

Tags: objective-c, xml, asynchronous

Hey, I have an iphone program that has a parser that parses some XML from a website and produces results.

It's not clear for me how to use the array of objects I create. I believe that the array is created correctly, but I don't know how to tell the mainview that the xml finished parsing and its time to get the result array and fill the view.

I did some test and i noticed that of course calling the parser and then getting the array results in having the array empty because the elements need still to be created.

Any suggestions?

Comment: As a comment I can add that I just tested and the array with the objects taken from the XML is correctly filled up, I just need to understand how to pass this array to the mainview that called in primis the XMLParser :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML parser will typically expect you to supply a delegate, a target and selector, or a block.  The documentation for the XML parser you are using should tell you what you need to know.

Comment: Well actually I'm using a class from my mainview that is called POSTAction, that calls the XMLParser (custom) which accept as delegate  the class POSTAction, but from the class POSTAction I don't know how to go back to mainview.

Comment: Let's change the question a little bit, since you seem to know a lot about this, in my situation (with a custom class POSTAction) how would you do what I am doing?

Comment: Nobody can understand what you're doing from that description. Try posting some code.

Comment: There are lots of different approaches you could take.  Without knowing more about your specific situation, it's impossible to say which approaches are suitable and which aren't.

Comment: Well thanks to all of you, I solved it by putting the POST action code in the mainview :) thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks to all of you, I solved it by putting the POST action code in the mainview :)